# I am trying to print an array in the reversed order but it is saying segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c

This is the code that I wrote to print the array in the reversed order. But, it is giving the output "segmentation fault". Please help and explain.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;
  scanf("%d",&a);
  int arr[a];
  for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  for(int j=a-1;j>=0;j++)
    printf("%d ",arr[j]);
}
```

Comment: If you printed values with a newline afterwards (`printf("%d\n", arr[j]);`) you'd very probably get something like `8 <ENTER> 6542323 <ENTER> -76523672542 <ENTER> 111632 <ENTER>Segmentation fault`; with the space, your program invokes segmentation fault before the output can be writen to the device.

Comment: `for(int j=a-1;j>=0;j++)`  Think about that line very carefully.... especially the `j++` part.

Answer (score 2):

You should have your second cycle decreasing `j` instead. In your code you wrote:

```
  for(int j=a-1;j>=0;j++)
    printf("%d ",arr[j]);
```

So after the first iteration j becomes `a` while you would like it to decrease by 1 at each step down to 0.

Comment: `j--`. Which is exactly why we shouldn't write loops like this. Bug prone and hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You should decrease your j index insted of increasing it.
Use following loop:

```
for(int j=a-1;j>=0;j--)

   printf("%d ",arr[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid writing loops that count in non-trivial ways. To print backwards, simply change the index:

```
  for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[a-i-1]);
```

Comment: Btw at least to me this version is less readable. Maybe this is subjective, but I prefer the OP's version (assuming it is corrected)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Now try to convert the OP's code to use unsigned types. Then this one.

Comment: Yes I agree to that, this has bitten me before.